How to share a variable between a program and dlopen-ed library?
I'm working on making my program extensible and plugin-able, which iterates on a directory containing shared libraries to load them as plugins, using the dlopen function.
I want to share a variable declared in my program, in such a way that it can be accessed through my plugins, and my plugins can also modify that globally, which means that the modified version will be handled through my program, not only my library. I'm almost done with the first task, and I can do the second part, but it's just messy.
For each variable I want to be shared, I can declare it in my program Type var;, and as I also build a shared library version of my program (name that library libP.so), I can load it in my library as void *var = dlsym(dlopen("./libP.so", RTLD_LAZY), "var");. But to modify it, I did the following which does not satisfy me at all:
I wrote a function in my program to modify that special variable (declared with extern "C" so I don't have to deal with name mangling):
extern "C" void modify(Type x) {
    var = x;
}

And to modify the variable in my library, did the following:
typedef void (*func_t)(Type);

func_t modify = (func_t)dlsym(dlopen("./libP.so", RTLD_LAZY), modify);
modify(/* the value that I want it to be modified to */);

Which means that I have to write a modify function in my program for each variable I want to be shared. I'm okay with all the variables being shared, so a solution letting all variables be modifyable in plugins won't bother me. That's actually what I want, and I'm not interested in writing a modify function for each variable.

Pack all the "shared" variables in a structure. Make this structure declaration in a header file accompanying your library. Define the modify function to take a pointer to such structure.... pretty much regular flow.

A struct is a good idea, but you could also pass a json string to your plugin-dlls (that way you can add more items later without having to recompile existing plugins).

share variable between dll-s is kind of code smell. Any global state shared is a bad thing. It would be better if you design API of your library in better way.

@MarekR I'm working on an open-source project (a game for Linux actually), and I want the plugin system to be as powerful as possible. I don't care about exploits that people might do by having every single variable being shared; they can just modify my program and have it that powerful and exploit it in their own version. Even if I don't implement a feature letting plugins access the variables, they can still hardly and messily modify the memory; that's why some programs such as Cheat Engine (or scanmem for Linux) exist.

"Plug-in" term comes from the hardware world, where you can have modules with compatible plugs and sockets. That is - well defined interfaces which only communicate specific signals between the modules. Same should be done in the software - define which "signals" you want to allow communicating and which should remain internal.

Consider defining some kind of initialization function for plugins to provide.  The application would call that function for each loaded plugin to initialize it, and in that way can provide pointers or references to any main program data the plugins should be able to access.  I would suggest bundling up the full set of such data in a struct.

This could be doable, if using global variables were not a bad idea.

Not that you shouldn’t consider the reengineering proposed in the other comments, but what stops you from declaring the variables in a header file and leaving them as undefined symbols in the plugins?


I want to share a variable declared in my program, in such a way that it can be accessed through my plugins

You are overthinking it: all that you must do is make the variable exported in the main executable's dynamic symbol table, and the dynamic loader will bind all references from plugin.sos to that definition.
See this answer.
Note: using -rdynamic is a "big hammer". On Linux your linker probably supports --export-dynamic-symbol, which is a smaller hammer.
